# Добавление div с уникальным id по кнопке JS

Tags: javascript, html

Реализовать генерацию рандомного id и закрепить за одним из множества div блоков созданных в js коде, всë должно проходить через js, есть идеи как это можно ркализовать?

Comment: Это не вопрос))

Comment: Задавайте Ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button class="btn">Add block</button>
  <div class="list">
    List
  </div>
</body>
</html>  



let list = document.querySelector('.list');
let btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let r = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
    const newBlock = document.createElement('div');
    newBlock.setAttribute('id', r);
    newBlock.textContent = 'new block'
    list.appendChild(newBlock);
})
```